# Check number of TCP connections

Tags: powershell

I need to check number of connections on given computer and if it is greater than 100 - kill process. My code:

```
IF ((Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established" | Measure-Object).Length -gt 100)
{
  stop-process -name Notepad
  Write-host Process killed!
}
Else {
  Write-host OK!
}
```

It is not working. How to convert "Connections Established" to string and make it work?
Newbie in PowerShell. Thanks.

I use script:

```
IF ((Get-Counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").CounterSamples.CookedValue -gt 100)
{
stop-process -name Notepad
Write-host Process killed!
}
Else {
Write-host not ok.
}
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> D:\Share\scriptif.ps1
DEBUG:    1+  <<<< D:\Share\scriptif.ps1
DEBUG:     ! CALL function 'scriptif.ps1'  (defined in file 'D:\Share\scriptif.ps1')
DEBUG:    2+ IF <<<<  ((Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").CounterSamples.cookedvalue -gt 100)
DEBUG:    8+  <<<< Write-host not ok.
not ok.
DEBUG:    2+         $foundSuggestion = <<<<  $false
DEBUG:     ! SET $foundSuggestion = 'False'.
DEBUG:    4+         if <<<< ($lastError -and
DEBUG:   15+         $foundSuggestion <<<<
```

When I try just (in command line):

```
(Get-Counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

I have empty result.

I tried new way with debug with no effect:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (Get-Counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").CounterSamples.CookedValue
DEBUG:    1+ (Get-Counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").CounterSamples. <<<< CookedValue
DEBUG:    2+         $foundSuggestion = <<<<  $false
DEBUG:     ! SET $foundSuggestion = 'False'.
DEBUG:    4+         if <<<< ($lastError -and
DEBUG:   15+         $foundSuggestion <<<<
```

Comment: (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples gives me Path                                         InstanceName CookedValue
----                                         ------------ -----------
\\hostname\tcpv4\connections established                      127

Comment: Please use [edit] button, do not add any information in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going step by step you can examine your output to see where you can find the number you're interested in. Let's start with checking what `Get-Counter` gives you:

```
PS> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established")

Timestamp                 CounterSamples
---------                 --------------
2019-10-09 11:20:09       \\hostname\tcpv4\connections established :
                          190
```

You have to get data from `CounterSamples` property, so let's examine that one:

```
PS> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples

Path                                         InstanceName CookedValue
----                                         ------------ -----------
\\hostname\tcpv4\connections established                      159
```

As you can see, what you want to find is in `CookedValue` property so you can change your `if` statement to:

```
if ((Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples.cookedvalue -gt 100) {
  # do something
}
```

---

Edit: as per comments, this is desired output with debug enabled (comments starting with `#` were added by me):

```bsh
# First I set debug
PS> Set-PSDebug -Trace 2

# Then I check CounterSamples
PS> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'

Path                                         InstanceName CookedValue
----                                         ------------ -----------
\\hostname\tcpv4\connections established                      186

# Then I check CookedValue
PS> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples.cookedvalue
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples.cookedvalue
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
192
```

For PowerShell 2.0 compatibility use `Select-Object` instead of `.CookedValue` as below:

```
(Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried (Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples and it shows 125. But when i use it with cookedvalue - it does not work. (windows 2008 r2 powershell.)

Comment: @Pavel, you were missing `CookedValue`, `CounterSamples` is just another PowerShell object.

Comment: if ((Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples.cookedvalue -gt 100) I use this script. and it does not work...

Comment: Check what `(Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples` gives you, and add to your **question** so we can investigate

Comment: ((Get-counter -Counter "\TCPv4\Connections Established").countersamples.cookedvalue  says it less than 2.

Comment: Add full output, please, I don't understand what `It says it less than 2.` means

Comment: You're running some `.ps1` file, but you haven't share its content, so it's still hard to say what's wrong. Make the file as simple as possible for easier troubleshooting and share its exact content (in question)

Comment: Still something is wrong as your output shows `$foundSuggestion` variable which is not in your code. Are you sure you run correct script?

Comment: Sorry, I give up, no idea what's going on here.

Comment: What get you on your machine while debug ON?

Comment: Added the output to my answer

Comment: I have powershell 2.0 And you?

Comment: On Windows 10 your script work well! On Windows 2008 R2 - not working.

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot. In PowerShell 2.0 `.CookedValue` doesn't work. Updated my answer with a workaround.